# prettyphoto opening image instead of lightbox

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my code for the last couple hours. It's doing my head in. My prettyphoto isn't working and I can't figure out what's wrong. It doesn't open up as a lightbox, it just opens in a new window??

Here's a link to the stripped down version:

http://v2.jrd.com.au/test.html

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: sorry I didn't think about doing that. Adrien gave me the fix (below) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a[rel='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    ...
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU that worked :) Why didn't it work with the ^ symbol? That was doing my head in lol

Comment: there was a problem of a missing `]` at the end ;)

Comment: LOL right, thought it would be something small and obvious haha I was raging at my code haha thanks so much, fresh eyes help most of the time ;)